# Assignment from ternary operator ignores remaining expression

Tags: javascript, ternary

Doing this

```
const bool = true;
const a = 2 + true ? 3 : 0;
const b = 2 + false ? 3 : 0;
```

gives me `a = 3` and `b = 0`. Why is the `2 +` being ignored?

Comment: `2 + false ? 3 : 0` evaluates to 3, not 0.

Comment: what is the desired output? and what is the use of bool variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with Operator precedence https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

As you can see in that table, addition (+) has a greater precedence than conditional (?). It makes the compiler read it like this:

```
(2 + true) ? 3 : 0
```

`2 + true` will evaluate first. As it is a truthy value, the result will be 3.
If you want to change the default behaviour of the operator precedence, you will need to add the parenthesis:

```
2 + (true ? 3 : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try writing like this :

//if the desired Output is a=5 and b=2

```
const a = 2 + (true ? 3 : 0);
const b = 2 + (false ? 3 : 0;);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const bool = true;
const a = 2 + true ? 3 : 0;
const b = 2 + false ? 3 : 0;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/74ds0der/

The code you have written gives a = 3, b = 3. Check out the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the 2 + being ignored?

It isn't. Given:

```
2 + true ? 3 : 0;
```

firstly `2 + true` is evaluated. Since *2* is a number, the `+` is treated as addition and *true* is coerced to the number 1, the result is 3.

Then the `?` causes 3 to be coerced to boolean *true* so of `3:0` the 3 is returned.

In the second expression:

- *false* evaluates to 0
- 2+0 evaluates to 2
- 2? evaluates to true, so 3 is returned.

Given:

```
const b = 2 + false ? 3 : 0;
```

*b* is assigned the value 3.